# Why there is no syntax fatal error in PHP with 2 pluses in a row?

Tags: php, syntax-error

Why there is no syntax fatal error in PHP with 2 pluses in a row?

For example: $a = $b + + $c;

PHP Version 5.6.38

```
$value = 5;
echo $value . " <br>\n";

$testBase = 10;
$testAdd = 7;
$value = $testBase + + $testAdd;
echo $value . " <br>\n";
```

The result is:

```
5
17
```

So calculations results are normal, but it will be better if there was fatal error as it have the same behaviour as $a = $b + $c;

Comment: Why do you expect that every occurence of "unexpected behaviour" should result in a fatal error?

Comment: Because it lead to unexpected results. But with @deceze answer I (another proger, really) realize that just was wrong with spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One is the addition operator, and the other the *unary* plus operator, a.k.a. the [identity operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). It converts the operand to a number. `-1`, `-$foo`, `+1`, `+$foo`.